# Prove that if $p$ is prime greater than $3$ ,then: $p^2+2015$ is multiple of $24$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Prove that if $ p $ is prime number $(p >3)$, then the number $p^2+2015$ is

multiple of $24 $?

Thank you for any help

Comment: No problem, thanks for thanking me :-)

Comment: Do you have any specific $p$ in mind?

Comment: only what i cited : p greater than 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All primes $p>3$ are of the form $6n\pm1$. But
$$(6n\pm1)^2 +2015=12n(3n\pm1) +2016$$
is divisible by $24$ since one of $n$ and $3n\pm1$ is even, and $2016=84\cdot24$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $-1 \equiv 2015 \pmod{24}$. So you can consider $p^2 -1$ instead of $p^2 + 2015$. For help with this see for example [Show that for any odd $n$ it follows that $n^2 \equiv 1 \mod 8$ and for uneven primes $p\neq 3$ we have $p^2 \equiv 1\mod 24$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380696/show-that-for-any-uneven-n-it-follows-that-n2-equiv-1-mod-8-and-for-uneve)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can show first that it is a multiple of 8, then that it is a multiple of 3.

Other method: you calculate the equation modulo 24 and for $p$ use all numbers with $\gcd(p,24)=1$ and $0<p<24$

Comment: That doesn't really rise to the level of an answer, you should probably have posted this as a comment.

Comment: @GregoryGrant OP asks for help, and this gives some.

Comment: @GregoryGrant should i give a full proof instead?

Comment: @MarkBennet Sure, but help comes in two forms, comments and answers.  This is a comment, as best as I can ascertain from the rules of the site

Comment: @supinf I don't think it has to be a full proof, there is not really a clear line between what constitutes an answer and what constitutes a comment.  But I left my comment before you made your first edit when it was just the first sentence.  That definitely was too minimal to be a answer.

Comment: @GregoryGrant ok in that case i an agree with you, i hope it is better now.

Comment: @supinf Actually I still think it's better as a comment, I still don't think what you have posted rises to the level of a bonafide answer.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I disagree - I think a hint is an answer to a question which asks for help.

Comment: @MarkBennet Obviously if somebody posts a question it is to get help, whether that is stated explicitly or not.  Therefore by your reasoning all responses should always be answers and never comments.  I disagree with that.

Comment: @MarkBennet Also, how helpful is it really to say something is divisible by $24$ is divisible by $3$ and $8$?  What if I just posted something like "$a$ divides $b$ if $\exists$ $c$ such that $b=ac$.  Use that when solving the problem."  That's help, but so minimal that it's useless.  The answer as posted is arguably not much better.  So where do you draw the line?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the fact that $2016=84\times 24$ to say transform the question to whether $p^2+2016-1=2016+p^2-1$ is divisible by $24$.

Further hints follow, which suggest a slightly different route through which avoids dealing with cases.

> Then any prime greater than $3$ is of the form $6n\pm1$ so that $p^2-1=36n^2\pm 12n=24n+12n(n\pm1)$

And we can then note:

> Then $n(n\pm1)$ is the product of two successive integers, hence is even.